# Xamarin.Mac - Send notification

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to send push notification with Azure Notification Hub and Xamarin.Mac.
I have this error, and I don't know why. Someone can help me to deal with it ?

The error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TimerManager' threw an exception. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateWaitableTimer
```

My code:

```
 private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
 {
     NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
         .CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string>", "<hub name>");
     string toast = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
         "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
           "<wp:Toast>" +
               "<wp:Text1>Content</wp:Text1>" +
           "</wp:Toast> " +
         "</wp:Notification>";
     await hub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several areas of that library that are Windows Desktop specific and are not available on Mono, UWP, Win10 IoT, etc.. (Items like `CreateWaitableTimer` are native Windows Desktop API calls).

Azure has a number of different clients and libraries, the most "portable" is the REST api, sending a MPNS Native Notification involves performing a POST to:

```
https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/messages/?api-version=2015-01
```

The docs show the content and headers required:

- [Rest API : Send an MPNS Native Notification](http://Send%20an%20MPNS%20Native%20Notification)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use the REST api. It seems that it's the best solution to my problem :) Thanks a lot!